# Supersymmetry v.s. BRST symmetry: QFT examples

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, mathematical-physics, supersymmetry, brst

**Questions**: Can any expert contrast the differences and similarities of

> **Supersymmetry (SUSY) v.s. BRST (global) symmetry**?

> (Question 1) What are the RULES and CRITERIA that having one symmetry implies that having the other symmetry? SUSY  v.s. BRST (global) symmetry.

> (Question 2) Is it true that we can only have a BRST charge $Q$? But we may have many SUSY charge $Q_i$.
> Are the two $Q$ charges related in some way?

Here let me give two QFT elementary examples and list some properties.

**Ex 1. SUSY example below (P&S QFT p.74):**
A complex $\mathbb{C}$ Lorentz scalar field $\phi$, a complex $\mathbb{C}$ Lorentz Weyl spinor field $\chi$, a complex $\mathbb{C}$ Lorentz scalar *auxiliary* field $F$. And an anti-commuting complex $\mathbb{C}$ Lorentz spinor field $\epsilon$ as a SUSY global transformation parameter.

**Ex 2. BRST (global) symmetry example below (P&S QFT p.517):** A  real $\mathbb{R}$  Lorentz 4-vector gauge field $A^a$, a real $\mathbb{R}$ Lorentz scalar *auxiliary* field $B^a$, a complex $\mathbb{C}$ Lorentz Weyl spinor field $\psi$. And an anti-commuting complex $\mathbb{C}$ Lorentz scalar field $\epsilon$ as a BRST global transformation parameter.

Comments:

- **1. Both have auxiliary field without their kinetic terms (so no dynamics?):**

Ex 1 has complex  $\mathbb{C}$ Lorentz scalar field $F$,

Ex 2  has a real $\mathbb{R}$ Lorentz scalar field $B^a$. (Just like $A^a$ is a real $\mathbb{R}$ field, but $A^a$ is a Lorentz 4-vector gauge field.)

- **2. Both have anti-commuting Grassman number $\epsilon$, but Ex 1 spinor and Ex 2 scalar:**

Ex 1 has anti-commuting complex $\mathbb{C}$ Lorentz spinor field $\epsilon$ .

But Ex 2 has anti-commuting complex $\mathbb{C}$ Lorentz scalar field $\epsilon$.

- **3. Ex 2 has ghost field, but Ex 1 does not require ghost field:**

Ex 2   ghost field has anti-commuting complex $\mathbb{C}$  Lorentz scalar field $c$.

- **4. Ex 1 needs not to be gauge theory, but Ex 2 is a (gauge-fixed constraint) gauge theory.**

[See how the BRST symmetry relates to gauge symmetry transformation.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/584390/42982)

- **5. Ex 1 has SUSY charge $Q$, while Ex 2 has BRST charge $Q$.**

Are two $Q$ charges related in some way?

## **Ex 1. SUSY example:**

[image]

## **Ex 2. BRST (global) symmetry example:**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 5):

A supersymmetry is a Grassmann-odd symmetry that takes Grassmann-even objects into Grassmann-odd objects, and vice-versa.

Main examples of supersymmetry:

1. [Poincare supersymmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersymmetry) (often abbreviated as SUSY). The [Poincare superalgebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-Poincar%C3%A9_algebra) is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ graded extension of the [Poincare algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group#Poincar%C3%A9_algebra). The number of supercharges $Q_A$ are labelled by an integer ${\cal N}$ times the number of components of the appropriate spinor (Dirac, Majorana, ...). The anticommutators of supercharges are proportional to momenta.
2. [BRST supersymmetry](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Becchi-Rouet-Stora-Tyutin_symmetry) (often called [BRST symmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BRST_quantization)). This encodes the gauge symmetry. There is only 1 BRST charge $Q$. It is Grassmann-odd, nilpotent and has ghostnumber 1.

The two above examples typically have nothing to do with each other per se, but they are allowed to co-exist (at least in component-form -- superfield formulation is more tricky). Both examples are $x$-independent/global symmetries, although global SUSY can sometimes be gauged into local SUSY aka. [SUGRA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supergravity).

Comment: Does my Ex 1 count as Poincare supersymmetry?